# Add layers to Spatialite Database using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatialite

I would like to add layers into a spatialite database. I have used the `QgsVectorFileWriter` method:

```
parcDisSHP='/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/FILE.shp'
parcelasDis = QgsVectorLayer(parcDisSHP, 'Parcelas_Unicas', "ogr")

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(parcelasDis, "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/database.sqlite", "utf-8", None, "SQLite", False, None ,["SPATIALITE=YES"])
```

But this method it seems good for create the database and insert just one layer. If I repeat the operation for other layers, this rewrites the Database again.

What should I do to add more layers to this DB?

Is there some others ways to do this operation?

Answer (score 2):

I will reply myself. This is not a direct aproach, but a workaround that it works:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["spatialite_tool", "-i", "-shp", "/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/PARCELA_xxxxx", "-d", "/home/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/villar.sqlite", "-t", "Parcelas", "-g", "Geometry", "-c", "UTF-8","-s","3042", "--type", "MULTIPOLYGON"])
```